# assertSame Junit testing

Tags: java, testing, junit

This is my method:

```
public static String passCheck(String x){
    return x; 
}
```

And here is my test for it:

```
Test
public void pass(){
    Testcases testcases = new Testcases();
    String y = "mypassword123";
    assertSame(y, testcases.passCheck(x)); 

}
```

How come there is an error saying variable x cannot be found?

Comment: Where is your "x" variable declared?

Comment: Didn't you mean to write `assertSame(y, testcases.passCheck(y));` ?

Answer (score 2):

> How come there is an error saying variable x cannot be found?

Because `x` isn't declared in `pass` - it's *only* declared in `passCheck`. It's not in scope in your test method. This has nothing to do with JUnit - it's just plain Java.

You want:

```
assertSame(y, testcases.passCheck(y));
```

Comment: Wouldn't this just compare y to itself? I wish to make sure x and y are the same.

Comment: @AdamHorrigan: No, it's going to compare `y` to the result of calling the `passCheck` method, where the argument passed to the method is the value of `y`. Why not try it? Change `passCheck` to return something else, and you'll see that it fails... It's not clear why you expected your original code to compile... leaving JUnit aside, how much experience do you have with Java in general? While I'm all for starting unit testing early, it's helpful to understand the basics of Java first.